# csharp: Visual Studio 2005 - command line

Tags: c#, scripting

I need to write a script in C# that makes new solution and project files, and builds them.

My understanding is that I need to write VS 2005 commands to accomplish this task. Can someone please tell me where to find a cheat sheet of C# commands? Or maybe there's a VS 2008 API for modifying/creating solution and project files?

Example:

```
Solution a = new Solution(); 
a.addProject("p.csproj");
a.Build(); 
...
```

I couldn't find this info after googling "C# commands, etc."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution and project files are just xml-documents, you can just create an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and fill in the required stuff.

To compile the result you can use [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) from command line.